# How to get the IP address when a session is created?

Tags: java, grails, servlets, httpsession

In my **grails** application, I have implemented the interface `HttpSessionListener` to listen for session creation as given below:

```
class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        log.info "***************** Session created: id= ${event.getSession()?.id}"
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to **log the IP address that is responsible for the session creation**.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can access the RequestContextHolder and get the value

```
String ipAddr = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
           .getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
```

Comment: Might as well mention that this is part of Spring framework. This classes are not part of the JSF specification.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't using the HttpSessionListener interface.

You can get and log the IP Address from "ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()" but you don't have access to the servlet request from HttpSessionListener or from HttpSessionEvent.

Best idea would to have a javax.servlet.Filter which gets the IP address and sets it as a session attribute if not already present. (You could also do the logging if not already present).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on setting the value to the session, as `HttpSession` is the only available instance within a `HttpSessionListener`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this interface in  your HttpSessionListener : ServletRequestListener
You can implement : requestInitialized() like this.

```
@Override
public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent servletRequestEvent) {
    this.request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequestEvent.getServletRequest();
}
```

it s working fine, the request object can bring you the remote adress, there is a méthod to do that