# Getting Request object from HttpSessionEvent

Tags: session, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a `Session` listener which extends `PortalSessionListener`. I have `sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent)` and `sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent)` methods

When my `Session` gets invalidated (after 15 mins as per my configuration in web.xml), my listener is called and `Session` is invalidated.

In my listener I want to clear off `Cookie` values before logging out the User. So, I want `Request` and `Response` objects so that I can clear off Cookie values and set it in `Response`.

But, how can I get `Request / Response` objects in my listener which has `HttpSessionEvent`?

I tried below code. But, this is not getting invoked when my `sessionDestroyed` method is called or any other phase for that matter.

```
public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent servletRequestEvent) 
 {
        log.debug("Entered into requestInitialized method");
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequestEvent.getServletRequest();

        log.debug("Request object created is :" +request);

 }
```

It has been suggested that implementing a `Filter` suits this requirement (for getting `Request` object). How that can be applied to my scenario?

Comment: FYI, PortalSessionListener that I have mentioned above implements HttpSessionListener.

Comment: Any more info required on this? Or its not at all possible to get Request Object in HttpSessionListener?

Answer (score 5):

This might be realated:

> you can access the RequestContextHolder and get the value
>
> String ipAddr =
>   ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
>              .getRequest().getRemoteAddr();

[Posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597083/how-to-get-the-ip-address-when-a-session-is-created)