# How to get request info on session created in Spring MVC?

Tags: session, spring-mvc, ip-address

I'm hoping to save some client info (IP address, etc) to a database on session created in Spring MVC.

I created a class implementing HttpSessionListener and configured it in web.xml. However, I'm not sure where to go after that.

Would like to be able to inject a bean as well (Spring Data JPA repository).

I've seen [How to get the IP address when a session is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597083/how-to-get-the-ip-address-when-a-session-is-created) , however if I try to access RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Session event listener threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bean this way with Spring java config:

```
@Bean
@Named ("IP")
@Scope ("session")
public String ip (HttpServletRequest request) {
  return request.getRemoteAddr ();
}
```

If all you want to do is log stuff then you should use the HttpSessionListener, please provide your source and full stack trace. Use pastebin.com if necessary.

Comment: Thx, but 1. That doesn't look like a Bean definition 2. I don't believe that will be instantiated unless it's called by some other code. Where would I call it from?

Comment: If you are using spring's component scan feature, just put it in a class annotated with @Configuration in a package where it'll get picked up. For more information look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06.html about java configuration way (although some of that may be outdated)